# The C++ standard versions vs Visual Studio versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The `/std (Specify Language Standard Version)` [option is available in Visual Studio 2017 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2017). Does it mean that previous versions of Visual Studio use particular versions of the C++ standard and, unlike gcc/clang, there's a 1:1 mapping between a VS version and the default C++ standard version provided by the compiler?

Comment: VC++, until recently, had numerous variances from standard C++ and this caused occasional incompatibilities. Much of this resulted from the way they implemented C++ before there was even a standard.

Comment: Yes but no.  Yes, C++ support in older Visual C++ compilers is determined by the compiler version.  No, it doesn't line up with specific editions of the standard.

Comment: _"unlike gcc/clang, there's a 1:1 mapping between a VS version and the default C++ standard version provided by the compiler?"_ GCC also defaults to a particular C++ standard, no? Until you write `-std=c++....`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yeah, you are probably right.

Comment: Related and details up to C++17: [Announcing: MSVC Conforms to the C++ Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/05/07/announcing-msvc-conforms-to-the-c-standard/). Note this is not Visual Studio which is the driver, but Visual C++ hosted by VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a blog post [Standards version switches in the compiler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/) that explains the introduction of the feature and what MSVC used to do previously:

> Traditionally, we would release the compiler in a default mode that combines features striding several versions of the C++ language, e.g. C++98, C++03, C++11, C++14, etc. in addition to conformance improvement bug fixes. This can lead to situations where it is difficult to simultaneously upgrade to the newer and better compiler and at the same time move your code forward. We really appreciate the great feedback you’ve given us about our conformance improvements and new feature work. As the C++ standards committee is gearing up for a new C++ version, we’ve taken the initiative to help you state in your build systems or compiler command lines which version of C++ you are comfortable with while updating to the next version of Visual C++.
>
> Visual C++ has made significant progress towards C++ standards conformance between the first release of Visual Studio 2015 and VS 2015 Update 3. We’ve fixed many issues with constexpr, improved expression SFINAE support, evaluation of initializer lists, variable templates, and more. Our standard library implementation has kept pace with features adopted into the post-C++14 standard draft. And we’ve implemented some major features currently under consideration by the committee, including C++ modules and coroutines. We want you to benefit from all this, but also we want you to consume these features at your own pace, while upgrading to this new update.
>
> All post-C++14 features implemented in this update are off by default; those which were included in previous releases are left on to avoid causing your builds.
>
> ...

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather `/std:c++17` would be equivalent to clang/gcc `-std=c++17` argument.

Some versions of msvc may not fully implement some versions of iso C++.

> Depending on the Visual C++ compiler version or update level, certain C++14 or C++17 features may not be fully implemented or fully conformant when you specify the /std:c++14 or /std:c++17 options. For example, the Visual C++ 2017 RTM compiler does not fully support C++14-conformant constexpr, expression SFINAE, or 2-phase name lookup.

(cf: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2017 )

So that's not exactly a "1:1 mapping between VS version and the default C++ standard version provided by the compiler".

You shouldn't rely on that. 
Instead you should read the docs for the version of VS you're using.

Hope this answers your question.